# what does prefixed exclamation mark (`!`) command mean/do in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

We usually use `$` as prompt in code block to demonstrate shell commands:

```sh
$ echo "hello world" > foo.md
$ cat foo.md
hello world
```

The problem is that you can't copy and paste those two lines with prefixed `$` into your Terminal and execute them.

```
bash: $: command not found
```

However, I accidentally found that you can use prefixed `!` for your commands (and prefixed `#` for outputs as comments)

```sh
! echo "hello world" > foo.md
! cat foo.md
# hello world
! ls
```

Now you can copy and paste above 4 lines into your shell and execute them at once.

Is that true? Is it worth to use `!` for demonstration within code blocks in markdown files?

What does prefixed exclamation mark (`!`) command mean/do in shell?

Comment: [Bash uses exclamation mark for history expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/understanding-the-exclamation-mark-in-bash#3748).

Comment: @XareeLee : A lone exclamation mark runs the command, but turns a non-zero exit code into zero and a zero exit code into 1. For instance, running `! true` will set `$?` to 1.

Comment: I would find `# hello world` extremely confusing in documentation, as I would read it as an instruction to run the command `hello world` as the root user. (`# ` is the default prompt for root.)

Answer (score 1):

As @chepner mentions below, the standalone `!` is acting as a [logical not](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Logical_Not_!) operator.

Beyond that, traditionally the `$` prefix indicates that the command should be run as an unprivileged user and the `#` prefix indicates that the command should run as a privileged user (root). See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/706190) for some more info.

Comment: The link to history expansion isn't relevant here. A standalone `!` negates the exit status of the pipeline it precedes.